# SQL Rollup with alias

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this sql query

```
Select 
  Case 
    When transfer.trf_type = 'c' then 'Transfer to own card' 
    When transfer.trf_type = 'o' then 'Transfer to own account' 
    When transfer.trf_type = 'I' then 'Transfer to a domestic bank' 
    When transfer.trf_type = 'b' then 'Transfer to another AIIB Customer' 
  End As Type , 
  Count(transfer.trf_type) As total, 
  Sum (transfer.amount*currency.rate) AS totalSum 
From transfer 
Inner Join currency on transfer.currency = currency.currency 
Where transfer.to_card IS null 
Group By Rollup(Type)
```

It gives me the result set with the sum but with an empty space.

I want the rollup row to appear with a specific alias , eg :"Total fund transfers".How can i achieve this?

Here is my query result, I need to add total in the last row

[image]

thank you

Comment: Wrap your query up in a derived table, including the case. Group By Rollup its result.

Comment: do you mean you want a column name with spaces?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
   with grpSum as (Select
          Case 
        When transfer.trf_type = 'c' then 'Transfer to own card' 
        When transfer.trf_type = 'o' then 'Transfer to own account' 
        When transfer.trf_type = 'I' then 'Transfer to a domestic bank' 
        When transfer.trf_type = 'b' then 'Transfer to another AIIB Customer' 
      End As Type , 
      Count(transfer.trf_type) As total, 
      Sum (transfer.amount*currency.rate) AS totalSum 
    From transfer 
    Inner Join currency on transfer.currency = currency.currency 
    Where transfer.to_card IS null
        Group By ROLLUP(Type))
        select COALESCE(Type,'Total found transfers'),total,totalSum from grpSum
```